# android application offline mode, local sqlite database synchronisation with distant database

Tags: android, sqlite, postgresql, synchronization, offline-mode

I have a **postgreSql database** which is manipulated by an android application via Web Services.
I'd like to know what is the best way to make an **offline mode** for my application.

My first idea was to make an **sqlite local database** used when the device has no access to web

I'd like to know if there is an existing tool, that makes **synchronisation** easier with the  existing postgres database once the device have access to web

Comment: you can try to use a SyncAdapter http://developers.androidcn.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html

Comment: Note that there's no simple solution if data can be modified in both databases while they are disconnected. What to do when there is a conflict is something that can only be decided by the application (or user).

Comment: @minhaz I learned a little about SyncAdapter but I'm not sur that it can helpful for what I want to do.


For example my application can be offline some days and it should permit to user to work "normally" using local data without Web Access, Once the device has again access to internet, I need to update/delete/create on the database items which were changed during the offline mode

Comment: Right now you have two issues, one is to make your app work offline and second Sync your database with cloud . it better to solve one problem at a time. You have to keep track of all saved and complete work using some temporary cache and when your user connect with internet process those one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some very basic thoughts on this.

In an ideal case, you'd sync in general working meta-data and your off-line mode would allow insert-only workflows adding new data based on that metadata.  This would make it fairly easy to sync things through later by merely posting to a web service sequentially and then flagging as such in the db or removing the rows altogether.

If you go with something like that, you probably don't really want to approach sqlite as an rdbms.  What you probably want is a wide table structure designed mostly to store pending requirests, or something that will store things like json payloads you will send later.  This means your local db will be designed not around your data model but around your web service API.

If you have to get into update (overwriting workflows) then you need to put a lot of effort into conflict resolution but the same basically applies.  You probably want to add a lot more information like timestamps and other conflict-resolution-related data.

From there however you should be able to re-use your application API to do the sync rather than looking for a specific tool to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wanted to know if there is a miraculous tool to do it but now I’m almost sure that this "magic" doesn’t exist yet.

Comment: I am not sure the "magic" is really possible if you have to do two-way sync.  There are some approaches to conflict resolution but one size fits all is not really possible there.  For one-way sync, it is reasonably possible but I am having trouble seeing why the web service you are already building wouldn't be better.....

Comment: The magic bullet for this problem seems to exist only for iOS from [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/datasync-beta) at the moment, it is only for iOS and as per their website, it will be made available soon for Android devices.